# Connecting iPhone camera to Raspberry Pi

Tags: camera, streaming-video, ios

Is it possible to capture images/video from an iPhone camera in real-time and display the image/Videos on a raspberry pi 3+?

Is there any software that could do this. Sort of opposite to VNC Viewer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it's not a raspberry pi related question, however, you can install a **spy camera** or **IP camera** application for your iPhone device. Just search for those keywords. [Here](https://www.tweaking4all.com/mobile-devices/ios/repurpose-old-ios/old-iphone-as-ip-camera/) is a nice installation. It will give you the camera's stream over a web page.

---

On your pi, open up the browser, VLC or whatever application/software/package to receive that streams in real-time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That’s really great  I’m carrying out real-time image classification on a raspberry pi 3 using a picamera and was exploring capturing images/video from a mobile device. 

Thank you again  Hopefully the IP camera should work a treat.

Comment: Of course it is. And, you should note that ask these kind of questions on [Ask Different SE site](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions). Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. Will do in the future. Best wishes

Comment: @Vikingmonkey Alright. Do that and inform the result here.